# C#, What's the easiest way to duplicate values from one int to another?

Tags: c#

I'm new to coding and i have this question, i need to assign values from num1, num2 and num3 to 4,5,6 and 7,8,9. is there any easier and nicer looking way to do this ? Thanks!

```
int num4 = num1;
int num5 = num2;
int num6 = num3;
int num7 = num1;
int num8 = num2;
int num9 = num3;
```

num1, num2 and num3 are taken from user input and i need to assign them to these 4,5,6,7,8,9 after modifying the values 1,2,3 for clarification!

Edit: So for more clarification i have this program where i need to print some numbers using 3 different loops for an assignment. I can't use the same values because they get changed after every loop, if i'm correct, i just wondered if there is a nicer way of doing that :)

```
            Console.Write("Enter a starting number: ");
            int num1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.Write("Enter a ending number: ");
            int num2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.Write("Enter a step-up number: ");
            int num3 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("\n");
             
            while (num1 > num2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error! First number has to be smaller than the 
                second one.\n");
                Console.Write("Enter a starting number: ");
                num1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Write("Enter a ending number: \n");
                num2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            }

            while (num3 == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error! Step-up number has to be bigger than 0, 
                enter a new number.\n");
                Console.Write("Enter a step-up number: ");
                num3 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            int num4 = num1;
            int num5 = num2;
            int num6 = num3;
            int num7 = num1;
            int num8 = num2;
            int num9 = num3;

            Console.WriteLine();

            while (num1 <= num2)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}", num1);
                    num1 += num3; ;
                }

                Console.WriteLine();

                do
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}", num4);
                    num4 += num6;

                } while (num4 <= num5);

                Console.WriteLine();

                for (; num7 <= num8;)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}", num7);
                    num7 += num9;
                }
```

Edit: Here's the final working code thanks to @Milney, i changed a tiny bit of the working part and removed the max,min.

```
using System;

namespace KT4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.Write("Enter a starting number: ");
            int firstNum = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.Write("Enter a ending number: ");
            int secondNum = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.Write("Enter a step-up number: ");
            int increment = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine();

            while (firstNum > secondNum)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error! First number has to be smaller than the second one.\n");
                Console.Write("Enter a starting number: ");
                firstNum = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Write("Enter a ending number: ");
                secondNum = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            }

            Console.WriteLine();

            while (increment == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error! Step-up number has to be bigger than 0, enter a new number.\n");
                Console.Write("Enter a step-up number: ");
                increment = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            }

            int whileCounter = firstNum;
            while (whileCounter <= secondNum)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", whileCounter);
                whileCounter += increment;
            }

            Console.WriteLine();

            int doCounter = firstNum;
            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", doCounter);
                doCounter += increment;
            } while (doCounter <= secondNum);

            Console.WriteLine();

            int forCounter = firstNum;
            for (; forCounter <= secondNum;)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", forCounter);
                forCounter += increment;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Look into loops

Comment: Without more details, I don't know what you can do simpler and more optimized than that.

Comment: I don't understand why you want to "copy" the value to multiple new variables rather than using the original in multiple places

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only changing one variable per example. You could name them more descriptively and reuse the two you aren't changing. Something like:

```
var max = num2;
var increment = num3;   

var whileCounter = num1;  
while (whileCounter <= max)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", whileCounter );
    whileCounter += increment ;
}

Console.WriteLine();

var doCounter = num1;
do
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", doCounter );
    doCounter += increment;
} while (doCounter <= max);

Console.WriteLine();

var forCounter = num1;
for (; forCounter <= max;)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", forCounter);
    forCounter += increment;
}
```

Comment: Oh, i didn't see the fact that i changed only one, thanks a lot! Could you explain why should you use var instead of int or when you shouldn't ?

Comment: Mostly a matter of preference. var just assumes the type by what you assign to it. So you have to use the full type in some cases (i.e. you are starting with NULL and want to assign a non-null value later), but in most cases you should just use var. Some people argue its clearer to type the full type - but if your code is clear anyway that should be a moot point

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use an array (so now `num1` is `nums[0]` etc)

```
int[] nums = new int[9];

nums[0] = 0;
nums[1] = 1;
nums[2] = 2;

//values are assigned from right to left so You can assign many in one line
nums[3] = nums[6] = nums[0];
nums[4] = nums[7] = nums[1];
nums[5] = nums[8] = nums[2];

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", nums)); //0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2
```

---

Or You can use loop:

```
for (int i = 3 ; i < nums.Length; i++)
{
    nums[i] = nums[i - 3];
}
```

Comment: Might be interesting to introduce the concept of loop here :)

Comment: Don't do this - I would absolutely reject a code review if someone randomly rewrote variable assignments into an array this way for no reason. You should write clean code that conveys its intention - using an array when one is not required is confusing